# IIS executes custom error handler synchronously in a single thread

Tags: multithreading, iis, asp-classic

I have found that IIS executes classic ASP script defined as custom error handler synchronously and in a single thread. **This is very slow**.

Here is my setup:

I have `index.asp` served by IIS Express 10.0. `index.asp` has 3 image elements (`<img src="..">`) with broken links that make IIS to call custom 400 error handler for each of the tags.

The handler is defined in `applicationhost.config` as

```
<httpErrors lockAttributes="allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated,defaultPath" errorMode="Custom" >
   <error statusCode="404" path="/handler.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

`handler.asp` logs its start and end times as

```
Log2File "start"
call main
Log2File "end"
```

and here are the times for the three calls:

```
3/10/2017 3:16:03 AM|start|http://localhost:8081/xENOjODFFUSZWDD
10-3-2017 3:16:12|end|http://localhost:8081/xENOjODFFUSZWDD

3/10/2017 3:16:12 AM|start|http://localhost:8081/pWEzIB25374ynkwv
10-3-2017 3:16:20|end|http://localhost:8081/pWEzIB25374ynkwv

3/10/2017 3:16:20 AM|start|http://localhost:8081/pMeODA30827gurud
10-3-2017 3:16:29|end|http://localhost:8081/pMeODA30827gurud
```

We can see that execution of handler is sequential: the first stops at 3:16:12
and the second starts as 3:16:12, etc.

I went to `TraceLogFiles` folder to see at which times requests to non-existent files come, maybe they come one after another?

Here are times of requests:

```
http://localhost:8081/pWEzIB25374ynkwv
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-03-10T01:16:03.586Z"/>

http://localhost:8081/pMeODA30827gurud
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-03-10T01:16:03.580Z"/>

http://localhost:8081/xENOjODFFUSZWDD
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-03-10T01:16:03.586Z"/>
```

We can see all the requests come at virtually the same moment.

So, I make a conclusion that the requests were put into a queue and processed one after another. No 3 threads were created to process 3 concurrent requests.
And this single thread executed them sequentially.

So, my question is:

**how can I make IIS parallelize execution of custom error handler?**

**UPDATE**

I did a small test. I put 5 iframes with corrupted src on `index.asp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe style="border: 2px solid red" width="1080" height="100" src="http://localhost:8081/none1"></iframe>
<iframe style="border: 2px solid red" width="1080" height="100" src="http://localhost:8081/none2"></iframe>
<iframe style="border: 2px solid red" width="1080" height="100" src="http://localhost:8081/node3"></iframe>
<iframe style="border: 2px solid red" width="1080" height="100" src="http://localhost:8081/none4"></iframe>
<iframe style="border: 2px solid red" width="1080" height="100" src="http://localhost:8081/none5"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I used classic asp to handle 400 error:

```
    <%
    Dim http, url
    Set http =  Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    url = "http://localhost:10000/"
    http.open "GET", url, False
    http.send()
    Response.Write( http.ResponseText )
    %>
```

On localhost:10000 runs a server that responses with delay of 10secs:

```
const logger = require('log4js').getLogger();
const uid = require('uid');
let app = require('express')()
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  let id = uid();
  logger.debug(`${id}: got request`);
  setTimeout( function() {
    logger.debug(`${id}: response sent`);
    res.send(`${id}: All ok`);
  }, 10000);
});

console.log('Listening on 1000');
app.listen(10000);
```

Here is what Network console of Chrome shows:

[image: ASP Classic]

Now, I use asp.net handler (which I define through Web.config):

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO


Public Class MySyncHandler
    Implements IHttpHandler

    Private Function GetText() As String
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:10000/")
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType( request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Console.WriteLine(Now() & "|Got status: " & response.StatusDescription)
        Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()
        Return responseFromServer
    End Function

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As _
            System.Web.HttpContext) Implements _
            System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim request As HttpRequest = context.Request
        Dim response As HttpResponse = context.Response
        Dim data As String = GetText()
        response.Write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'/></head>")
        response.Write("<body>")
        response.Write(data)
        response.Write("</body>")
        response.Write("</html>")
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean _
            Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And the picture from Network console look quite better:

[image: ASP.NET]

So, the problem is with Classic ASP handler.

Is there a way to improve it?

Comment: Don't you think the problem is that your error page needs 9sec to execute? Make it a faster (<100ms) and don't worry about the synchronous execution. I doubt you can change the execution model.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf The job in Error handler takes long time and, sadly, 9 sec is not an upper limit. I'm new to .NET and wonder if implementation of async http handler  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx) as a custom error handler can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have the issue because of Session. Session is synchronous no matter if it's asp or asp.net, it's initialized/locked on begin request event and released only after the request is ended. So you need to make the requests session-less if you'd like to make them working asynchronously. Or you can use a different approach, like background jobs or handlers, but they also won't use sessions.

Comment: But why does not IIS open 5 threads for 5 sessions in classic asp error handler and DO open 5 threads to process requests in parallel for asp.net? Where in the above asp.net script do I NOT set session? And how do I disable session in classic asp?

Comment: Because you have the same session cookie in the browser and it identifies all 5 requests for the same session. You can disable it of couse by <%@ EnableSessionState=False %>

https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/244465/how-to-turn-off-asp-session-state-in-active-server-pages-and-iis

Comment: Thanks alot. This's what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would use URL Rewrite module for this kind of task. Are you able to somehow describe those broken links as patterns? If not and you can simply put .* as a pattern and add 2 conditions:

{REQUEST_FILENAME} is not a file
{REQUEST_FILENAME} is not a directory

and then change the action to REWRITE and use this as a rewrite URL:

/handler.asp?path={R:0}

where handler.asp is your file that will process those missing files.

In your handler.asp get path=request("path") and process it however you like.

Custom error module hasn't been updated for many years I believe and URL Rewrite module is much newer. It is also multithreaded.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot apply your solution: Only custom error handler can be used. 
Also, as I mentioned in the UPDATE, custom error handler which is written in ASP.NET code is multi-threaded. Can you provide some reference to this: "Custom error module hasn't been updated for many years"?